# Edge column in pgr_dijkstra

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I am using pgr_dijkstra for finding the shortest path between two given nodes. The network map is actually a grid based one and I have created all the necessary columns and working fine. But I do not understand how does the id2 (which is edge) given?

[image: Query in QGIS]

The values given for id2 (e.g., 59721224, 59721496 ...) can not be found any of my tables. So how does this id2 (edge) values are given? Every single time I query pgr_dijkstra, id2 values are changing but none of the other columns are changing.

This is how my wp_norway_network1 table looks:
[image: wp_norway_network1]

Comment: It might help if you can show (illustrative) data on your input network.

Comment: I have added my input network 'wp_norway_network1' table screenshot here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. In my query presently I have

'SELECT gid AS id'

changing that to

'SELECT gid::integer AS id'
 solved the problem.

Comment: This issue stumped me for too long. As well my source/target id numbers were Navteq reference ids, which were in the billion range. Passing these in as source/target caused the same issue where the returned vertex ids were randomly something else. I assume it has something to do with integer overflow in the C code.

Answer (score 2):

id2 `59721224` for example is the edge that connects vertex IDs `2` and `3`. That's why the last record has a value of `-1`.

Edge ID is the `id` you specify in the first argument (SQL query) of the `pgr_dijkstra` function. In your case it's the `gid` of the table named `wp_norway_network1`. 
Because `pgr_dijkstra` requires the column name `id`, you had to write `gid AS id`.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of my wp_norway_network1 table. As you can see, there is not edge id with 8 digits ((e.g., 59721224, 59721496 ...) . All the gid in that table are 4 digits. So my problem is, how does it get those 8 digit edge ids?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to look at this with screenshots. Would you be able to send some sample data, which allows to reproduce your case, to the pgRouting mailing list? This would make it easier to find out, if it's a bug.

Comment: You can find my question here with the files:
http://pgrouting-users.974093.n3.nabble.com/pgrouting-users-Edge-column-in-pgr-dijkstra-tt4025368.html

Comment: The files are uploaded again to make it accessible for everyone:
http://pgrouting-users.974093.n3.nabble.com/pgrouting-users-Edge-column-in-pgr-dijkstra-td4025368.html